# What happened to Tyler Lockwood since his appearance in The Originals?

Tags: vampire, the-vampire-diaries, the-originals

He said something about the [end of the vampire species](https://youtu.be/vioPwtz7SCk?t=211), probably related to what's going on this season. Then we haven't seen him since. I stopped watching The Vampire Diaries, but apparently he's still there. What happened? Why is he in Mystic Falls and not New Orleans?

Answer (score 1):

Tyler's appearance on *The Originals* was only intended to be a brief special appearance. He leaves Caroline in *The Vampire Diaries* to go get revenge on Klaus, and when he shows up in *The Originals*, we learn what he has planned.

He has formulated a theory about Klaus and Hayley's baby. Specifically, he believes that the child will be born a hybrid vampire/werewolf and that her blood could be used to create more. *That* is what Tyler was talking about in his conversation with Marvel: if Klaus has access to make an unlimited number of hybrids, he will choose them over the vampires and the vampires won't have any way to stop him. Tyler plans to kill the baby, both to prevent this potential hybrid army, and to get back at Klaus for killing his mother.

His last appearance on screen in New Orleans, he's being taken hostage by Marcel and Rebekah, probably bricked up in "the Garden" with the other trapped vampires; sometime later, off-screen, Rebekah lets Tyler out.

He returns to Mystic Falls after that, showing back up during the 500th episode, and becomes involved in the ongoing plot lines (at that point I believe it was the Travelers bit) and gets involved with one of the Gemini witches, Liv.

Last I saw (I'm way behind this season), Tyler has taken Elena's body somewhere and is protecting it for and/or from Damon.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but what the Hell? Is this supposed to make sense? Why isn't he back in New Orleans?

Comment: He only went to New Orleans to confront Klaus... and lost. I assume he decided it was a bad decision and went back home where he was more welcome. I'll go pull up the episode on Netflix and see if he says anything specific about it.

Comment: right thanks. Probably the writers decided to not involve him in TO :p

Comment: You might need to update it with TVD season 8 updates about him